# Associative law of scalar and matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> Prove that $$c(AB)= (cA)B= A(cB)$$ where $A,B$ are matrices with $AB$ is defined  and $c$ is a scalar.

I don't know where to start, so I guess we start there. This is a theorem that is used in my textbook, and my professor stated that we should practice proving some of these for the test. I can see that this is true but I can't put it into a proof. Obviously it's true just thinking about it, but how do you even start to prove this.

Comment: The most direct way to show two matrices are equal is to compare their entries. So you may compute the $(i,j)$-th entry of $c(AB)$, $(cA)B$ and $A(cB)$ by definitions. (To start with, suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{kl})$ for example.)

Comment: I am still confused. How can I use =() and =()?

Comment: Of course you need to know the entries of $A$ and $B$ so that you can compute $AB$. Do you know what is the $(i,j)$-th entry of $AB$ given that $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{kl})$?

Comment: I haven't heard of it... should I look up a video for it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this properly, you're going to need proper definitions for scalar and matrix multiplication.

Start with scalar multiplication first, as it's easier. If $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, and $c$ is a scalar, then
$$(cA)_{ij} := c(A)_{ij}.$$
This is to say, the new matrix which we are calling $cA$, has an entry in its $i$th row and $j$th column equal to the entry of $A$ in the same position, just multiplied by $c$. More briefly, we form $cA$ by multiplying each entry by $c$.

A little more complicated is the definition of matrix multiplication. If $A$ is $n \times m$ and $B$ is $m \times k$, then we define
$$(AB)_{ij} := \sum_{t = 1}^m (A)_{it} (B)_{tj}.$$
You should convince yourself that this is indeed the definition of matrix multiplication that you're familiar with: each entry is the dot product between the appropriate row of $A$ and the appropriate column of $B$.

Now we have what we need to actually do a proof. We have,
\begin{align*}
(c(AB))_{ij} &= c(AB)_{ij} & \ldots \text{ by definition of scalar multiplication} \\
&= c \sum_{t = 1}^m (A)_{it} (B)_{tj} & \ldots \text{ by definition of matrix multiplication} \\
&= \sum_{t = 1}^m c(A)_{it} (B)_{tj} & \ldots \text{ by the distributive property of real numbers} \\
&= \sum_{t = 1}^m (cA)_{it} (B)_{tj} & \ldots \text{ by definition of scalar multiplication} \\
&= ((cA)B)_{ij} & \ldots \text{ by definition of matrix multiplication.}
\end{align*}
Since they are equal in each entry, we therefore have
$$c(AB) = (cA)B$$
as required. Try showing they are equal to $A(cB)$ yourself!